# How to mock if a local variable in a list in Python?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I'm trying to mock the if food in a list, can someone tell me how to do it? Thank you!

```
def method_a():
    food = "apple"
    if food in ["apple", "banana"]
        do something...
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand what you wrote: "mocking" is a term that is used when we try to imitate an object or a behavior of a function, we don't "mock"  an `if` condition.
Could it be that you want to mock `entity` to return either an `"apple"` or a `"banana"`when `getattr` is called on it ?

Comment: @Nir Alfasi Hi Nir, what i'm trying to ask is how to mock the local variable food's value, so that if food in ["apple", "banana"] could return true.

Comment: Typically the word 'mock' is in relation to a test case being run. If you have such a case, you should include it. Refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on how to create a minimal example of the question you have so that we can properly answer it.

Comment: You can't patch names that are local to a function's scope. If `food` had been initialized like `food = some_function()`, then you might be able to patch `some_function` to control the value of `food`, because `some_function` would not be a local variable inside `method_a`.

Comment: Theoretically, you could patch `list.__contains__`, but you aren't allowed to modify attributes of the built-in type.

Comment: @NirAlfasi I only mention it to explain which "thing" would need to be patched. It's not physically possible to do so, but really, it's no worse than patching any other non-local name in `method_a`.

Comment: @chepner I agree, and I wouldn't want to even raise such an idea :)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the question was modified since the first iteration.
The way it it's being now - you *cannot* mock `food` since it's a local variable of the function (as @chepner suggested in the comments!).

One thing you can do, is pass `food` from the caller into the function:

```
def method_a(food):
    if food in ["apple", "banana"]
        # do something...
```

by doing this - you'll make it easy for your tests to "inject" the value that you want to test for.

In general, the approach of [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) (DI) which is also sometimes called IoC (inversion of control) is recommended to make your code cleaner and testable.